# How do I apply xdt transforms on app.config on installing/updating nuget package?

Tags: c#, asp.net, nuget, app-config, xdt-transform

I recently updated one of my nuget packages so that it now requires an app setting to be present on the consuming project. I would like to add a app.config transform to the package to that anyone consuming the new version of my package will have this app setting populated with some default values. To that effect, I followed [this post](http://docs.nuget.org/create/configuration-file-and-source-code-transformations) to create the app.config.install.xdt file.

```
   <?xml version="1.0"?>
   <configuration xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform">
       <appSettings xdt:Transform="InsertIfMissing">        
          <add key="CustomSetting" value="CustomValue" />
       </appSettings>
    </configuration>
```

I also added a line my nuspec according to [this stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5766324/nuget-web-config-transform-issue)

```
     <file src="\Content\app.config.install.xdt" target="app.config" />
```

However, when I install/update this package in the consumer, I do not see this app setting show up in the app.config of the consumer. Is there any other step I am missing?

Comment: You should also add xdt:Transform="InsertIfMissing" to your <add key ... /> entry too. Otherwise when you update your package the key will be inserted again.

Answer (score 6):

The nuspec file entry does not look correct. It should be something like:

```
 <file src="Content\app.config.install.xdt" target="content" />
```

Your target is app.config which is not correct. The .xdt transform needs to be in the content directory inside the NuGet package.

Comment: What do you mean - "The .xdt transform needs to be in the content directory inside the NuGet package"?  Do you mean to say, the process is to create the nupkg file, then open it and modify it?  Or do you mean in the VS project create a folder called 'content' and place the .xdt files there?

Comment: It means there should be content directory inside the NuGet package (.nupkg). You do not need to open and modify the .nupkg file you can generate it using the `nuget pack` command. You do not need to create a folder in the Visual Studio project.